# Extracting numbers from string in perl

Tags: regex, perl, extract

I'm having a problem coming up with an expression that would print out only "123" from "LOL123." I cannot use regex to solve this, so I must compare the string somehow. This is the code I have so far:

```
print join '', grep{$_ + 0} split //, "LOL123";
```

This works, but gives me a warning that L, O, L are nonnumeric.

Is there any possible way to do this without getting an error?

Comment: If you know how to use a hammer for a nail, why bother about trying to use a saw instead?

Comment: @Jan professor doesn't want us to use regex....

Comment: Then please provide some real input strings.

Comment: If you wanted all the digits, e.g. "1234" from "1LOL234", then maybe grep would be useful.  If you want to find and capture the digits at the end or the first group of digits or anything like that, it wouldn't be.  Define your problem more clearly.

Comment: @ysth Yes, I want to capture all the digits.

Comment: `grep` in Perl does not do necessarily do string matching.  It is a filter to find items in a list that match a condition.  For example `@evens = grep { $_ % 2 == 0 } @numbers`.

Comment: And what if your string is something like `ABC123DEF456`?

Comment: @Borodin It'd never be like that because in this specific case of mine, the letters are first and numbers after like a course number.

Answer (score 1):

To split a string into a list of characters, use `split //`, not `split / /`.

Then the code in the grep needs to test whether `$_` (which grep will alias to each character in turn) is a digit.  Normally you'd use a regex for that, but you could use be string comparison operators `ge` and `le`.

Comment: So I have it as:
print join '', grep{$_ + 0} split //, "LOL123";
It gives me an error that L O L is not numeric, but it still prints out the 123 fine. How would I use ge?

Comment: That will only keep 1-9.

Comment: Hint: a digit is one of the strings '0', '1', ..., '9'

Comment: I tried grep{$_ eq '0' || '1' || ... || '9'} but doesn't work... I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: You'd need to do `$_ eq '0' || $_ eq '1' ...`.  That would work, but using ge and le would be easier.

Comment: How would you do it by using ge or le?

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to ord($_) le 65. Thanks for your help

Comment: `$_ ge '0' && $_ le '9'`.   or you could do ord($_) >= 48 && ord($_) <= 57.  using 65 will let through a bunch of non-digit, non-letters, and ord() and 65 are numbers so you would want a numeric `<=`, not the string `le`